# how to show notification message in my webpage using signalR when delete a record in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, signalr

how to show notification message type in the corner of  my webpage using signalR when delete a record in Jqgrid

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question that whether the message to be displayed is returned by the server or not. If you want just to display a message in the same client, you may not need SignalR and you can do this with javascript itself or try using some jQuery plugins (like jQuery dialog). SignalR is a technology for establishing realtime communication channel with the clients and the server.

**Update**

To broadcast a message to all the connected clients, you may setup a SignalR hub and define a method similar to this:

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Broadcast(string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcast(message);
    }
}
```

You also need to setup the client side javascript function to receive the call for the broadcast.

See how to setup the SignalR Hub [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) and about the Javascript client [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client).

Comment: message will be display all clients who are using this application

Comment: In that case, SignalR is the best choice for ASP.net website. Answer updated.